# Adding multiplayer to HTML5 canvas game

Tags: html5-canvas, multiplayer

Let's say I have similar simple HTML5 canvas game in website: [LINK](http://www.zeewe.com/blog/html5-canvas-demo-tictactoe/)

**What are the options to add multiplayer to this?** By that I mean one user can play with other.

- Tutorial?
- Blog post I didn't find?
- Library specially for that?
- Or you know to say few works about that?

First there's a *Play* button which then "keeps loading" when clicked until anyone else presses the button too & it automatically hooks up these 2 users - very simple construction, nothing too complicated.

I've done my homework & I didn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some options, but for a basic tic-tac-toe game I'd use a database.

Connect the clients to the database, updating the move they make from both sides and voila, you've got yourself a (slow) multiplayer game.

Alternatively, check out this tutorial to try it with javascript (ajax): https://jadendreamer.wordpress.com/2012/04/26/ajax-tutorial-2-player-tic-tac-toe-game-no-database-required/